# Redis_Proxy installation error in MAC

Tags: redis, haproxy, node-redis

I couldnt able to install redis proxy in my Mac Mini. I am getting below error message.
server:$ sudo npm install -g redis-proxy

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis-proxy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis-proxy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis-proxy
npm ERR! Error: socket hang up
npm ERR! at SecurePair.error (tls.js:927:23)
npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.done (tls.js:625:22)
npm ERR! at CleartextStream.read as _read
npm ERR! at CleartextStream.Readable.read (stream_readable.js:304:10)
npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.onCryptoStreamFinish (tls.js:292:47)
npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.g (events.js:175:14)
npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR! at finishMaybe (streamwritable.js:344:12)
npm ERR! at endWritable (streamwritable.js:351:3)
npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.Writable.end (streamwritable.js:329:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! npm-@googlegroups.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Want to change the npmjs url to GET http://registry.npmjs.org/redis-proxy